# How to get require('http').createServer().listen(port).on('connect', fn) to work on Openshift 3 Online?

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-3, openshift-online

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(...).listen(8080);
server.on('connect', (req, cltSocket, head) => {
  console.log('This step will never be activated!');
  ...
  if (...) {
    let srvSocket = net.connect('9999', '127.0.0.1', () => {
      cltSocket.write('\r\n\r\n');
      srvSocket.write(head);
      srvSocket.pipe(cltSocket);
      cltSocket.pipe(srvSocket);
    });
  }
});
```

On Openshift 3 Online `require('http').createServer().listen(port).on('connect', fn)` will never be activated. Do anyone knows the mechanism behind this challenging behavior and how to resolve it?

P.S. This is not really a duplicated question because in "How to open an internal port in Openshift 3 Online" the question is about opening an internal port. The extended question is "How to get require('http').createServer().listen(port).on('connect', fn) to work on Openshift 3 Online."

Comment: Why are you connecting to a socket on the loopback interface? You can just transfer the socket reference directly to the Node.js process that needs access to the stream, it's a lot more efficient than bidirectionally tunneling the socket connection.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to open an internal port in Openshift 3 Online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868635/how-to-open-an-internal-port-in-openshift-3-online) Please do not write new questions to gain attention for your unanswered question. Either modify your original question if you feel that the answers given there aren't sufficient, or consider placing a bounty if you feel it wasn't given enough attention.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts laziness mostly. Because I wrote a method separately originally for a different purpose. Now I kinda want to know if it is possible. This is not really a duplicated question because  in "How to open an internal port in Openshift 3 Online" the question is about opening an internal port. The extended question is "How to get require('http').createServer().listen(port).on('connect', fn) to work on Openshift 3 Online."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openshift Online blocks 'connect' event, its reverse proxy handles it and returns a 502 error. The event never reaches your pod.